# Weird display on Android Studio's emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm running Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 and I get weird artifacts on the emulator's screen, as you can see in the image provided (see bottom righ hand corner).

This is just an example. Sometimes, the display is correct, and sometimes it shows black areas, usually in the bottom of the screen, as in the image below.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image: emulator's screen]

Answer (score 0):

That's looking odd, try to change emulator and if that doesn't help check your log files

and try to launch a simple app on the same emulator, and see if those pixels are dead too- if so, I guess the issue is in the emulator in that case- just get a new one.
if they are displaying double check your code :)

Comment: Those pixels are not dead. When the display is refreshed, they can get their 'real" color, and the whole screen can be correctly drawn, or other pixels can become black.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be solved after Android system image update.